# Calling function defined in JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have defined a function something like below in the top of the jsp page

```
<%!
  public boolean isSkillSelcted(String Skill1)
  {
     ...
     .. 
     . 
     return true;
  }
%>
```

Now I want to call the Function in the Check box as below

```
<input name="chkSkills" type="checkbox" id="chkJava" value="Java" 
       <c:if test='${isSkillSelcted("Java") == true}'>Checked</c:if>>Java
```

If the function return true then the check box will be marked as checked.Its Displaying exception as below.

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /EditUser.jsp(73,71) 
The function isSkillSelcted must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
```

When i append fn at beginning fn:isSkillSelcted its complaining function undefined

[image]

Comment: why dont you use javascript

Comment: If you can avoid it, don't write plain Java in your JSP pages. You should move the method in a Javabean, and call the corresponding bean property from a simple EL expression in your JSP.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `${isSkillSelcted("Java")}` is a call to an Expression Language function.
When you use Expression Language function, you have to declare it in a `.tld` file, and to specify a prefix to use them. This is explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaiq).

If you declare your function in the JSP page, you have to call it like this :

```
  <input name="chkSkills" type="checkbox" id="chkJava" value="Java" 
  <% if (isSkillSelcted("Java")) { %>Checked<% } %> >
```